# Empty line validation in excel using selenium+C#

Tags: line

I have an excel sheet with groups of data.
Each group is differentiated with an empty line.

eg:
group 1:
data 1       data 2         data 3
data 4         data 5         data 6
data 4         data 5         data 6

group 2:
data 1       data 2         data 3
data 4         data 5         data 6
data 4         data 5         data 6

group 3:
data 1       data 2         data 3
data 4         data 5         data 6
data 4         data 5         data 6

So, here i need to validate whether the empty line is present or not.
i need to do it using selenium webdriver + C#.
Please do come up with some solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

No sure if you can use Selenium for that.

For me it seems that you could use pure C#.

- Hard way: If you've access to excels data, you should use Regex for
  parsing it.
- Ease way: `yourString.Split(new[] {Environment.NewLine},
  StringSplitOptions.None);`